# 1 in ASCII and 1 in Binary. Same thing?

Tags: binary, ascii

So, this question goes in the computer science world.
So, if we write number 1 in binary it will give us:

```
00000001
```

but we know that if 0 = 48, then 1 = 49 (in ASCII). So, if we represent 49:

```
00110001
```

are those two numbers the same?

Comment: Clearly not. 1 is 1 and 49 is 49. The character `'1'` is different from the numeral *1*.

Comment: So you can't actually perform operations between characters?

Comment: You can perform operations on the numbers that represent characters, which is basically the same thing. I'm not sure exactly what your question is..

Comment: I think you're confusing representation with actual values. `49` (decimal) and `00110001` (binary) and `'1'` (the ASCII character) are just different ways of displaying the same value.

Comment: ```1 in ASCII and 1 in Binary``` - You answered your question yourself.

Comment: 00000001 implies there is something with a width of 8. That thing hasn't been introduced in the question.